# Como implementar o GAITrackedViewController do Google Analytics para iOS juntamente com o UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics-api

Como inserir o GAITrackedViewController do Google Analytics no código abaixo sem retirar o UITableViewController desta linha?

```
@interface STNavigationViewController:UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

Essa possibilidade existe? No meu caso preciso implementar os dois recursos.

Código completo:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface STNavigationViewController:UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

}


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;



-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;


@end
```

Comment: De fato, não existe uma implementação do Google Analytics para sobrescrever uma `UITableViewController`, o que você pode tentar é utilizando esse *tracker* manual em suas views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `GAITrackerViewController`, não passa de uma "conveniência" para o desenvolvedor não perder tempo fazendo tracking do tipo Screen View.

Eu de verdade, acho uma besteira estender o `GAITrackerViewController`, já que é muito simples fazer o tracker de uma view quando ela é exibida.

Minha sugestão para você não ficar engessando suas views controllers no tracker do Google para não ter mais este tipo de problema é criar uma abstração do GAI que pode ser simples e reutilizavel para qualquer projeto.

Eu criei [um gist que pode ser util para você](https://gist.github.com/jancassio/f8ffda0460c6bc44d3d3). Não testei ele pois eu não estou na minha maquina de desenvolvimento, só peguei um trecho de um codigo desenvolvido anteriormente e adaptei para sua necessidade. De quebra tem Flurry também mas, se não precisar de tanto é só remover.

Espero ter ajudado.